# New York park along an old elevated railway?

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city

I seem to recall reading an article a few years ago about a plan to open a park in New York, I think Manhattan, along what was once an elevated railway line.

What I can't remember was exactly where, or what it was called, so I can't check to see if it's open yet. Does anyone know if this park has been finished yet and is now open? And if so, how easy it is to visit (arriving by public transport, and likely leaving from a different bit), and what it's like?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The High Line](http://www.thehighline.org/) is open and [accessible](http://www.thehighline.org/visit) by

> Subway
>
> - A / C / E to Penn Station at 34th Street and 8th Avenue
> - 1 / 2 / 3 to Penn Station at 34th Street and 7th Avenue
> - L or the A / C / E to 14th Street & 8th Avenue
> - 1 / 2 / 3 to 14th Street & 7th Avenue
> - C / E to 23rd Street & 8th Avenue
> - 1 to 18th Street & 7th Avenue
> - 1 to 23rd Street & 7th Avenue
>
> Bus
>
> - M11 to Washington Street
> - M11 along 9th or 10th Avenue
> - M14 to 9th Avenue
> - M23 to 10th Avenue
> - M34 to 10th Avenue

There are also Citibike stations nearby every few blocks along 9th, 10th and 11th Avenues.

Check the website for advisories, as some entrances may be closed in winter due to ice.

Comment: I saw this question on the frontpage, and I was all excited to have a question that I could answer.... :( ....very well put together answer, +1